# confiuring customDeadLetterQueue using a direct queue instead of net.msmq

Tags: wcf, msmq

So I have set up MSMQ on my WCF service. I am using msmqIntegrationBinding to dump emails into the local queue directly then my service grabs them and processes them, it all works just fine but I am trying to add a custom dead letter queue and although it seems to work, i.e. it doesn't put my service in a faulted state, the custom queue I defined never ends up with anything in it. I think the issue is that I am trying to use a direct queue instead of a net.msmq value as my customDeadLetterQueue value.

Let me try to be more clear with some examples. All the samples I have seen look something like this.

```
 <binding name = "CustomDLQ"
       deadLetterQueue = "Custom"
       customDeadLetterQueue = "net.msmq://localhost/private/MyCustomDLQ">
   </binding>
```

My configuration looks like this.

```
  <msmqIntegrationBinding>
    <binding name="EmailProcessorBinding" 
             deadLetterQueue="Custom" 
             customDeadLetterQueue="msmq.formatname:DIRECT=OS:.\private$\failedmessages" 
             durable="true" 
             receiveRetryCount="2"
             receiveErrorHandling="Move" 
             maxRetryCycles="3"  >
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </msmqIntegrationBinding>
```

notice the customDeadLetterQueue? Does that just not work? Or did I make a mistake elsewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you address the queue using the net.msmq address format?

Comment: Yeah, I think I was just confused. I didn't end up needing to tell what to do at all, thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently I missed this due to my lack of experience but I didn't need to explicitly tell it the queue I wanted to use, this is ultimately how I ended up configuring the binding.

```
<msmqIntegrationBinding>
 <binding name="EmailProcessorBinding" 
                     durable="true" 
                     receiveRetryCount="0"
                     receiveErrorHandling="Move" 
                     retryCycleDelay="00:20:00" 
                     maxRetryCycles="3" >
  <security mode="None" />
 </binding>
</msmqIntegrationBinding>
```

Notice that i didn't need to tell it anything about what to do with failed messages. It will simply put them in a sub-queue called poison when it fails, no configuration needed.

[image: sub queue with poison message in it]